# Computing input gradients for different targets efficiently

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I am working on a problem similar to adversarial examples. In my setting, I want to compute gradient masks with respect to the input samples based on the gradients for different classes. More specifically, I have an input image x and want to compute the individual pixel-wise loss gradients given the target class is 0, 1, 2, ....

My current solution looks something like this toy example:

```
net = torch.nn.Sequential(torch.nn.Linear(10, 10), torch.nn.ReLU(), torch.nn.Linear(10, 5))
x = torch.randn(1, 10)
x.requires_grad = True

y = net(x)
losses = torch.nn.functional.mse_loss(y, torch.tensor([0., 1., 2., 3., 4.]), reduction='none')[0]
gradients = []
for loss in losses:
    loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
    gradients.append(x.grad.clone().detach())
    x.grad.zero_()
```

Since the loss is currently sequentiall backpropagated for each target value, the run time is not really good. Is there any more efficient way to compute the gradients for the different classes in a single backward pass? Since my memory is also somewhat limited, simply copying the input sample and run it multiple times in parallel is no option.

I already tried to make copies of the input to run the backward passes in parallel. Unfortunately, the memory of my GPU is limited in this setting.

Comment: Why are you not using a reduction? Any particular reason? You can try to look into torch jacobian function. It may return what you want.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your suggestion. Using a reduction (sum, mean, etc.) only provides a single gradient map for the input. For my setting, however, I want the pixel-wise gradients for the input x given the different target labels. The reason for this is to compute an input mask based on the alignment of the gradients for different classes. So my approach requires the gradients given label 1, label, 2, etc. but in separate tensors.